# Suspended NSURLSessionUploadTask resume when applicationWillEnterForeground for the second time

Tags: ios, swift, networking, background-task, nsurlsessionuploadtask

i created a NSURLSessionUploadTask task

```
private lazy var uploadSession: NSURLSession = {
    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("com.foo.bar")
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    return session
}()

let task = uploadSession.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
```

after creation i am **not** calling task.resume()

when i press the home button and return to the app the task is still in "suspend" mode, but when i to this process again, all the tasks that i created change the state to resume and starts uploading.

i didn't find anything in apple docs that can lead to such behavior, any ideas ?

edit:

see the example project - https://github.com/valeriyvan/NSURLSession-test

Comment: Xcode project to illustrate this bug or whatsoever is here https://github.com/valeriyvan/NSURLSession-test

Comment: Opened radar for this https://openradar.appspot.com/26864489